# Java Integer.parseInt() for 32-bit signed binary string throws NumberFormatException

Tags: java

Is this Java Api's bug?

```
    int i = 0xD3951892;
    System.out.println(i); // -745203566
    String binString = Integer.toBinaryString(i);
    int radix = 2;
    int j = Integer.valueOf(binString, radix );
    Assertions.assertThat(j).isEqualTo(i);
```

I expect it to be true without any question. But it throws below exception:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "11010011100101010001100010010010"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:495)
at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:556)
at com.zhugw.temp.IntegerTest.test_valueof_binary_string(IntegerTest.java:14)
```

So if I have a binary String , e.g. 11010011100101010001100010010010, How can I get its decimal number（-745203566） in Java? DIY? Write code to implement below equation?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Integer.valueOf(String, int radix)` and `Integer.parseInt(String, int radix)` will only parse numbers of value -2 147 483 648 to 2 147 483 647, i.e. the values of 32-bit signed integers.

These functions cannot interpret two's complement numbers for binary (`radix = 2`), because the string being passed can be of any length, and so a leading 1 could be part of the number or the sign bit. I guess Java's developers decided that the most logical way to proceed is to never accept two's complement, rather than assume that a 32nd bit is a sign bit.

They read your input binary string as unsigned 3 549 763 730 (bigger than max int value). To read a negative value, you'd want to give a positive binary number with a `-` sign in front. For example for `-5`:

```
Integer.parseInt("1011", 2); // 11
    // Even if you extended the 1s to try and make two's complement of 5,
    // it would always read it as a positive binary value
Integer.parseInt("-101", 2); // -5, this is right
```

Solutions:

I suggest, first, that if you can store it as a positive number with extra sign information on your own (e.g. a `-` symbol), do that. For example:

```
String binString;
if(i < 0)
    binString = "-" + Integer.toBinaryString(-i);
else // positive i
    binString = Integer.toBinaryString(i);
```

If you need to use signed binary strings, in order to take a negative number in binary two's complement form (as a string) and parse it to an int, I suggest you take the two's complement manually, convert that into int, and then correct the sign. Recall that two's complement = one's complement + 1, and one's complement is just reverse each bit.

As an example implementation:

```
String binString = "11010011100101010001100010010010";
StringBuilder onesComplementBuilder = new StringBuilder();
for(char bit : binString.toCharArray()) {
    // if bit is '0', append a 1. if bit is '1', append a 0.
    onesComplementBuilder.append((bit == '0') ? 1 : 0);
}
String onesComplement = onesComplementBuilder.toString();
System.out.println(onesComplement); // should be the NOT of binString
int converted = Integer.valueOf(onesComplement, 2);
// two's complement = one's complement + 1. This is the positive value
// of our original binary string, so make it negative again.
int value = -(converted + 1);
```

You could also write your own version of `Integer.parseInt` for 32-bit two's complement binary numbers. This, of course, assumes you're not using Java 8 and can't just use `Integer.parseUnsignedInt`, which @llogiq pointed out while I was typing this.

EDIT: You could also use `Long.parseLong(String, 2)` first, then calculate the two's complement (and mask it by 0xFFFFFFFF), then downgrade the `long` down to `int`. Faster to write, probably faster code.

Comment: Note that a shorter way to obtain the negative equivalent of a signed to complement number n is simply to do ~n + 1

Comment: I was trying to get around `Integer.valueOf` not interpreting 32-bit two's complement binary strings, though—so I essentially did `~n` as a string, and did the `+1` after interpreting it. However, I realise after writing that solution that it would be possible to do `Long.parseLong(String, 2)`, do the two's complement arithmetic as numbers and then cast it back to `int`.

Comment: Thanks!  In short, it's very non-intuitive when processing negative and radix is two. But as a general api， it can only be this.

Comment: In addtional, someone told me BIgInteger could help in this situation. e.g.   BigInteger bigInteger = new BigInteger(Integer.toBinaryString(Integer.MIN_VALUE), 2);
  Assertions.assertThat(bigInteger.intValue()).isEqualTo(Integer.MIN_VALUE);

Answer (score 6):

The API docs for `Integer.toBinaryString(..)` explicitly state:

> The value of the argument can be recovered from the returned string s by calling `Integer.parseUnsignedInt(s, 8)`.

(as of Java 8u25) I think this is a documentation error, and it should read `Integer.parseUnsignedInt(s, 2)`. Note the `Unsigned`. This is because the `toBinaryString` output will include the sign bit.

Edit: Note that even though this looks like it would produce an *unsigned* value, it isn't. This is because Java does not really have a notion of unsigned values, only a few static methods to work with ints as if they *were* unsigned.

Comment: See my edit: You already have -745203566. There are no unsigned ints in Java.

Comment: Have you at least tried to use parseUnsignedInt instead of dismissing my answer? You should not need Integer.valueOf at all.